# ArgumentError (Signing key must be provided) in Rails + Carrierwave + Microsoft Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, heroku, carrierwave

I've been doing some coding practice and i need to know how to provide the necessary credentials to my app in order to stablish a connection to Microsoft Azure and upload images in my app running in production with Heroku.

I'm using CarrierWave gem as The Rails tutorial shows to upload images in production. I'm using Microsoft Azure instead of using AWS and my `carrier_wave.rb` is structured like this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
    require 'azure/storage/blob'

    blob_client = Azure::Blob::BlobService.

    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        blob_client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService.create(
            storage_account_name: my_account_name,
            storage_access_key: my_account_key
        )
    end
end
```

But when i push to Heroku and i try to upload a image in my app it crashes

The logs here:

```
2019-02-23T04:01:46.917324+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.917249 #10] DEBUG -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70]    (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-02-23T04:01:46.917957+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.917872 #10]  INFO -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 112ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
2019-02-23T04:01:46.918790+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.918718 #10] FATAL -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70]
2019-02-23T04:01:46.918843+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.918781 #10] FATAL -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70] ArgumentError (Signing key must be provided):
2019-02-23T04:01:46.918891+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.918837 #10] FATAL -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70]
2019-02-23T04:01:46.918942+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-02-23T04:01:46.918891 #10] FATAL -- : [d1de016d-29a7-4338-b6f0-071aced60e70] app/controllers/books_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

I've followed examples of how provide the information needed from Microsoft Docs but it's seems i'm not doing the integration properly. I would appreciate the help in this question.

Comment: What gem version of azure are you using?

Comment: I'm using azure (0.7.10), azure-core (0.1.15), azure-storage-blob (1.1.0), azure-storage-common (1.1.0) according to "gem list" command

Comment: From where are you getting my_account_name and my_account_key? are you sure there are valid?

Answer (score 0):

From where are you getting `my_account_name` and `my_account_key`? are you sure there are valid and has value?

According to [BlobService#initialize](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby/blob/master/blob/lib/azure/storage/blob/blob_service.rb#L166) -> [SharedKey#initialize](https://github.com/Azure/azure-ruby-asm-core/blob/9b3af533df5f557d4d9c2b40076c4aefd0dab9a2/lib/azure/core/auth/shared_key.rb#L31) -> [Signer#initialize](https://github.com/Azure/azure-ruby-asm-core/blob/766f7ad69074a4ad233e4e36650612f0fa287ce7/lib/azure/core/auth/signer.rb#L31)

your `acces_key` is `nil`

```
# Initialize the Signer.
#
# @param access_key [String] The access_key encoded in Base64.
def initialize(access_key)
  if access_key.nil?
    raise ArgumentError, 'Signing key must be provided'
  end

  @access_key = Base64.strict_decode64(access_key)
end
```

Comment: I put those variables names for security but I'm getting the values from my azure's portal. 'Account name' and key 1 as the azure documentation says.

Comment: Try upgrading the azure ruby gem.